# JS time - make an array for each year between two dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, time

I have two variables:
 Start & End 
and basically I need to create an array for each complete year between these two dates.

I will need to record the total withdrawals taken in each year in the array but not sure how to start creating the array for each policy year.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are `Start` and `End` ? Date object ? String ?

Comment: Can we see some code for what you've tried?

Comment: What do you need to do with the arrays you've created? Fill them with the records, and store them where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do a lot of date manipulations, I'd recommend using Moment.js. With the Moment.js [diff](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) function, Moment.js will do an exact calculation on differences and not just subtract the year component on the Date object.

Example spanning 2 years:

```
var Start = new Date("June 26, 2012 11:13:00");
var End = new Date("January 1, 2015 11:13:00");
var years = moment(End).diff(Start, 'years');
var yearsBetween = [];
for(var year = 0; year < years; year++)
    yearsBetween.push(Start.getFullYear() + year);
```

Returns:

```
yearsBetween
[2012, 2013]
```

Example spanning 3 years:

```
var Start = new Date("June 26, 2012 11:13:00");
var End = new Date("June 26, 2015 11:13:00");
var years = moment(End).diff(Start, 'years');
var yearsBetween = [];
for(var year = 0; year < years; year++)
    yearsBetween.push(Start.getFullYear() + year);
```

Returns:

```
yearsBetween
[2012, 2013, 2014]
```

The first example only spans 2 years because it does not have 3 full years, even though the year on End is 3 years later than the year on Start. Anything beyond the same month/day of the start date in a later year counts as a full year. This is why the second example spans a full 3 years.

EDIT:
Example of how to do a diff without moment.js:

```
const msPerYear = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;

function diffYear(d1, d2) {
  const utc1 = Date.UTC(d1.getFullYear(), d1.getMonth(), d1.getDate());
  const utc2 = Date.UTC(d2.getFullYear(), d2.getMonth(), d2.getDate());
  return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / msPerYear);
}
```

Spanning 7 years:

```
var Start = new Date("June 26, 2012 11:13:00");
var End = new Date("January 1, 2020 11:13:00");

var diff = diffYear(Start, End);
```

Returns:

```
7
```

Spanning 8 years:

```
var Start = new Date("June 26, 2012 11:13:00");
var End = new Date("June 26, 2020 11:13:00");

var diff = diffYear(Start, End);
```

Returns:

```
8
```

Note: It gets complicated when calculating the diff with leap years as they change the milliseconds per year for just the years which are leap years.

Answer (score 9):

For simple scenarios (where using a library would be overkill) , I would use this:

```js
const rangeOfYears = (start, end) => Array(end - start + 1)
  .fill(start)
  .map((year, index) => year + index)
```

If your input is not an integer but a `Date` object, use `.getFullYear()`

---

So for instance, if we wanted the years between **2014** and **2020** (inclusive), this would be:

```
// Using integers for years
rangeOfYears(2014, 2020)

// Using `Date` objects for years
rangeOfYears(new Date("Jun 26 2014").getFullYear(), new Date().getFullYear())

// For both the result would be:
// [2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]
```

Although the title does not state this, the question author mentions *"each complete year between these two dates"*. An exact definition of what constitues a "complete" year is not mentioned, but that could either be:

1. **Years that have a full 12 months**
   In this case, the first and last item should always be removed:

   ```js
   .slice(1, -1)
   // Which gives: [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]
   ```
2. **Each 12 months from the start date onwards**
   In this case, a filter would be needed to see if the last year falls within range:
   <sup>(This would require `Date` objects to work with)</sup>

   ```js
   .filter((year, index) => 
       // 31536000000 = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 1000 = one year in milliseconds
       index < (end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / 31536000000)
       // Which gives: [2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]
   ```

---

### Code examples

Putting all of this together gives us:

#### Without "complete year" filter

```js
/* Example without "complete year" filter */
const rangeOfYears = (start, end) => Array(end - start + 1)
  .fill(start)
  .map((year, index) => year + index)

let a = rangeOfYears(2014, 2020)
let b = rangeOfYears(new Date("Jun 26 2014").getFullYear(), new Date().getFullYear())

console.log(a)
console.log(b)
```

#### With "complete year = 12 full months" filter

```js
/* Example with "complete year = 12 full months" filter */
const rangeOfYears = (start, end) => Array(end - start + 1)
  .fill(start)
  .map((year, index) => year + index)
  .slice(1, -1)

let c = rangeOfYears(2014, 2020)
let d = rangeOfYears(new Date("Jun 26 2014").getFullYear(), new Date().getFullYear())

console.log(c)
console.log(d)
```

#### With "complete year = each 12 months" filter

```js
/* Example with "complete year = each 12 months" filter */
const rangeOfFullYears = (start, end) => {
  
  // Lets not do this inside the "filter"...
  const fullYears = (end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / 31536000000
  
  return Array(end.getFullYear() - start.getFullYear() + 1)
    .fill(start.getFullYear())
    .map((year, index) => year + index)
    .filter((year, index) => index < fullYears)
}

let e = rangeOfFullYears(new Date("Jun 26 2014"), new Date())

console.log(e)
```

Comment: This would work, but it only gets the year component of a Date object and doesn't respect whether a complete year is between two dates. The OP asked for complete years between a `Start` and `End` date. That's why using a library or a function for calculating a diff between two dates might be preferred.

Comment: The definition of what constitutes "a complete year" seems rather vague to me... To explain what I mean, I'll use "Jun 26 2014" as a start date and today (May 12 2020) as end date. --- Should I include 2014 and exclude 2020 (As there is a full year from 2014-06-26 to 2015-06-26, but not from 2019-06-26 to 2020-06-26)? Or should I exclude both 2014 and 2020 (As neither has 12 full months by itself)?

Comment: @CameronTinker I've updated my answer to reflect insights from your comment. 

Comment: Yes, the "full year" concept is vague, but this looks to solve the date range of full years well. My only suggestion would be to use UTC dates as they aren't affected by timezone time changes.This is a nice clean update!

Comment: Why `Array(end - start + 1)` works, while `[end - start + 1]` doesn't?

Comment: @bertdida Because `Array(n)` creates an array with `n` items, while `[n]` creates an array with _one_ item with the value `n`. You can see this by running `n=8; console.log(Array(n), [n])`. For more details visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array and have a look at `arrayLength`.

Answer (score -1):

This function takes a start date object, and an end date object and returns an array of years between the two dates. It does not handle any errors for you. It simply takes the start date and end date and expects them to be valid date objects, with the end date being later than the start date.

```
var calculateYearsBetween = function(startDate, endDate) {
    var startYear = startDate.getYear() + 1900, //The start year
        endYear = endDate.getYear() + 1900,     //The end year
        output = []                             //Initialize the output

    // For each year between push that year into the output
    for ( var year = startYear; year <= endYear; year++ ) output.push(year)

    // Return the output
    return output
}
```

**Usage**

```
calculateYearsBetween( new Date("Jan 1 2012"), new Date() )
```

Here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/63p9u/1/)

Answer (score -1):

So i tried the first solution and i got back a negative number so the for loop would not run. Here is the solution i came up with afterwards:

```
export function yearsBetween() {
    const currentYear = moment();
    const backYear = new Date("January 1, 2015");
    const years = moment(backYear).diff(currentYear, 'years');
    const iterator = Math.abs(years) + 1;
    const yearsArray = [];

    for (var year = 0; year < iterator; year++) {
        console.log(currentYear.format("YYYY"))
        yearsArray.push(parseInt(currentYear.format("YYYY")) - year);
    }

    return yearsArray;
}
```

What i did was use Maths.abs() to change it to a positive number and then added 1 to get the actual year in the mix.